# How to write test case for recyclerview drag and drop using espress

Tags: android, testing, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I am writing test cases for recyclerview. I am stuck with drag and drop test in recyclerview. I tried in some way. But not able to write drag and drop test for recyclerview.

In recyclerview I am having drag button. Using of that button I am drag and drop the item on position to other position.

My code to swipe bottom to top

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
                    RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, new GeneralSwipeAction(
                            Swipe.SLOW, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER, GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER,
                            Press.FINGER)));
```

This code is swipe the recyclerview.

So I am trying like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
                RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,
                        MyViewAction.clickChildViewWithId(R.id.img_drag)),new GeneralSwipeAction(
                        Swipe.SLOW, GeneralLocation.TOP_RIGHT, GeneralLocation.CENTER_RIGHT,
                        Press.FINGER));
```

But this is not workout to me. Please let me any idea to test the drag and drop functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The code you wrote first clicks the drag handle and then swipes from top right of the first item to its center right. If you want to drag and drop an item, you will need several custom `CoordinatesProvider`s.

1. `RecyclerViewCoordinatesProvider` will find coordinates of an item within your RecyclerView:

```
class RecyclerViewCoordinatesProvider(private val position: Int, private val childItemCoordinatesProvider: CoordinatesProvider) : CoordinatesProvider {
    override fun calculateCoordinates(view: View): FloatArray {
        return childItemCoordinatesProvider.calculateCoordinates((view as RecyclerView).layoutManager!!.findViewByPosition(position)!!)
    }
}
```

2. `ChildViewCoordinatesProvider` will find coordinates of a child with a given id:

```
class ChildViewCoordinatesProvider(private val childViewId: Int, private val insideChildViewCoordinatesProvider: CoordinatesProvider) : CoordinatesProvider {
    override fun calculateCoordinates(view: View): FloatArray {
        return insideChildViewCoordinatesProvider.calculateCoordinates(view.findViewById<View>(childViewId))
    }
}
```

3. Lastly we will create new custom general locations, which will provide coordinates above and under a View (I assume we are reordering inside a LinearLayoutManager):

```
enum class CustomGeneralLocation : CoordinatesProvider {
    UNDER_RIGHT {
        override fun calculateCoordinates(view: View): FloatArray {
            val screenLocation = IntArray(2)
            view.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation)
            return floatArrayOf(screenLocation[0] + view.width - 1f, screenLocation[1] + view.height * 1.5f)
        }
    },
    ABOVE_RIGHT {
        override fun calculateCoordinates(view: View): FloatArray {
            val screenLocation = IntArray(2)
            view.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation)
            return floatArrayOf(screenLocation[0] + view.width - 1f, screenLocation[1] - view.height * 0.5f)
        }

    }
}
```

Now if you want to drag an item `from` the original position `to` the target position where `RecyclerView`'s ID is `server_list` and the drag handle's ID is `drag_handle`, use the following method:

```
private fun reorder(from: Int, to: Int) {
        onView(withId(R.id.server_list)).perform(GeneralSwipeAction(
                Swipe.SLOW,
                RecyclerViewCoordinatesProvider(from, ChildViewCoordinatesProvider(R.id.drag_handle, GeneralLocation.CENTER)),
                RecyclerViewCoordinatesProvider(to, if (from < to) CustomGeneralLocation.UNDER_RIGHT else CustomGeneralLocation.ABOVE_RIGHT),
                Press.FINGER))
    }
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. it just scrolls the recyclerview... i suspect this is because there is nothing to initiate the drag action.
for example if i want to drag on long click, i am missing that "press and hold" action. any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @or_dvir The original question is about testing reordering which is initiated by dragging a "drag handle". If your app initiates reordering by a long press, then you probably can't use the GeneralSwipeAction but create your custom action which will first hold the "finger" on the view to simulate long press and then start swiping.

Comment: @ Miloš Černilovský dragging by handle or by long press... either way we need to simulate "press and hold" on a view. whether its a specific view (the handle), or the root view of the list item shouldn't matter

Comment: @or_dvir The difference is that in your case the "finger" must stay in one place for a while (long press but without the UP event) to initiate the dragging and then start moving (swiping). In case of a handle the swipe is performed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example, although I do not know if it works with scrolling, and it throws an Exception if it fails.

The idea is to create a custom `ViewAction` that acts on a `RecyclerView`. `MotionEvents` are created and injected into the uicontroller. `GeneralLocation`, despite its name, is used to get accurate coordinates for the view holders.

I tried to use `MotionEvents.sendMovement` previously, but it did not work, so it appears that the interpolation is necessary in order for the phone to process the event.

```kotlin
    class MoveViewHolder(val fromPosition: Int, val toPosition: Int) : ViewAction {

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View?>? {
            return allOf(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView::class.java), isDisplayed())
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Long click ViewHolder #$fromPosition and swipe to position $toPosition"
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View?) {

            // For long clicking the ViewHolder
            val rv = view as RecyclerView
            rv.scrollToPosition(fromPosition)
            val viewHolder = rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(fromPosition)!!
            val location = GeneralLocation.CENTER.calculateCoordinates(viewHolder.itemView)
            val downEvent = MotionEvents.obtainDownEvent(
                location,
                floatArrayOf(0f, 0f)
            )
            // For moving the ViewHolder
            val viewHolder2 = rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(toPosition)!!
            val location2 = if (toPosition > fromPosition) {
                GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER.calculateCoordinates(viewHolder2.itemView)
            } else {
                GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER.calculateCoordinates(viewHolder2.itemView)
            }
            // Interpolating the move
            val longPressTimeout = (ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() * 1.5f).toLong()
            var eventTime = downEvent.downTime + longPressTimeout
            val durationMS = 1500
            val steps = interpolate(location, location2, 10)
            val intervalMS: Long = (durationMS / steps.size).toLong()
            val events = mutableListOf<MotionEvent>()
            for (step in steps) {
                eventTime += intervalMS
                events.add(MotionEvents.obtainMovement(downEvent.downTime, eventTime, step))
            }
            eventTime += intervalMS
            events.add(
                MotionEvent.obtain(
                    downEvent.downTime,
                    eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    location2[0],
                    location2[1],
                    0
                )
            )
            // For releasing the ViewHolder to its new position
            val upEvent = MotionEvents.obtainUpEvent(downEvent, location2)
            events.add(upEvent)
            
            try {
                uiController.injectMotionEvent(downEvent)
                rv.scrollToPosition(toPosition)
                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(longPressTimeout)
                uiController.injectMotionEventSequence(events)
            } finally {
                downEvent.recycle()
                for (event in events) {
                    event.recycle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```